# Rx BehaviorRelay doesnt keep the data when return from a view

Tags: swift, rx-swift, behaviorrelay

I have an app that have 3 views and a service logic layer. The services is sending messagings all the time to all this views.What I do to control all this data was use RxBehaviorRelay.

To this point all works great, I match the variables with the services layer and I am receiving data in the ViewController 1, 2 and 3.

The problem comes when I am on the view2 and then go to view3 and return to view2. On this return I lost all the changes and the BehaviorRelay object is like the beginning.

[image: App diagram]

My code in the view1 is like this one

```
class View1: UIViewController {
    var service: ServiceModel? = ServiceModel()
    
    var observableView1 = BehaviorRelay(value: [Object]())
    var observableView2 = BehaviorRelay(value: [Object]())
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        service!.observableView1 = self.observableView1
        service!.observableView2 = self.observableView2
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destination = segue.destination as! View2
        destination.observableView2 = self.observableView2
    }
}
```

Code of view2

```
class View2: UIViewController {
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
    var observableView2 = BehaviorRelay(value: [Object]())
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        fillTable()
    }
    
    func fillTable() {
        observableView2.asObservable().bind(to: tvData.rx.items) { (tableview, row, data) in
            //code to fill the table
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

On the service layer I only receive the changes and put in the BehaviorRelay object.

```
observableView2.accept(changes)
observableView1.accept(changes)
```

As I said I obtain all the changes in the view2 but when I move to view3 and return to view2, the changes gone.

Sorry for my english.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All relays, subjects and observables should always be declared using `let`, never with `var`. Once you make this fix, you will notice why you are loosing your changes.

Based on your description, I would expect something more like:

```
final class Service { 
    private let _observableView1 = BehaviorRelay(value: [Object]())
    private let _observableView2 = BehaviorRelay(value: [Object]())
    let observableView1: Observable<[Object]>
    let obserrvableView2: Observable<[Object]>
    init() { 
        observableView1 = _observableView1.asObservable()
        observableView2 = _observableView2.asObservable()
    }
}
```

Then pass the Service to View 2, or subscribe to the service inside the prepare method.